# Proving that a function is a constant in Undergraduate Complex Analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I am trying to show that if f is an entire function and its real part is less than c, then f is a constant.  I'm pretty sure this is related to Liouville's Theorem, which directly states that if F is entire and if there is a constant M such that the absolute value of F(z) is less than M, then F is identically constant.  However, I am not exactly sure how to prove this as related to the particular question.  The question is attached as an image.  Any hints, suggestions, and pointers would be very helpful.  Thank you.
[Proof F is a Constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddTf5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddTf5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your $\exp\circ f$ is holomorphic and it holds that $|\exp(f(z))| = \exp(Re f (z))$. Use proof by contradiction if necessary.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I follow.  Is there way to prove this incorporating Liouville's Theorem?

Comment: I'm not sure why exp(f(z)=exp(Ref(z))?

Comment: Because $Re f(z)$ is bounded, then so is $\exp (Re f(z)) = | \exp (f(z))|$. This means that you can use Lioville on $\exp ( f(z))$.

It also holds that $\exp(x +iy) =  \exp(x)\cdot \exp(iy)$ which mean that $|\exp(x +iy)| =  \exp(x)$ for real $x,y$.

Comment: So exp(f(z) is bounded as well?

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear and give more explanation, I'm really trying to understand?

Comment: How do you show that f is a constant?  I want to know how to apply Liouville's Theorem and how to know that the absolute value of F(z) is bounded.

Comment: You apply Lioville on a bounded function $\exp(f(z))$.

Comment: So exp(f(z)) is bounded because the Re(f(z)) is bounded? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Ok thanks this was helpful.  Could you just explain like in words why the Re(f(z)) being bounded results in exp(f(z)) being bounded.  This is the only part I do not get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56436/discussion-between-vadavad-and-bob).

Comment: Okay, I sent you a message.